# Call PHP function using javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want call a PHP function using Javascript(No Jquery)

MY php function is

```
<?php

function helloworld() {
    echo 'Hello Ashish Srivastava';
}
?>
```

in hello.php file
and my JavaScript is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function getRoute() {
                var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = "hello.php";

            hr.open("helloworld", url, true)
                hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-from-urlencoded");
                hr.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if (hr.readyState === 4 && hr.status === 200)
                    {
                        var return_data = hr.responseText;
                        alert(return_data);

                    }
                }
                hr.send();
            }
        </script>
```

and HTMl is

```
  <input type="button" value="Hello" onclick="getRoute()"/>
```

bt when i am calling this function i get nothing from server plz help

Comment: because you are calling a page not function.to do that i think you need to have some MVC architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to pass a query parameter.

Tell Javascript to use a url like

```
host.local/my-script.php?callFunction=helloWorld
```

and tell php to process the [request](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) object

```
<?php
    //fetch query parameter
    $callFunction = $_REQUEST['callFunction'];

    //define hello world function
    function helloWorld() {
        echo 'Hello Ashish Srivastava';
    }

    //test the query parameter and call helloWorld
    if($callFunction == "helloWorld")
       helloWorld();
```

Answer (score 1):

AJAX doesn't call PHP functions, it calls pages.  E.g., `hello.php`:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello Ashish Srivastava';
?>
```

Comment: So is there any way of call function using ajax

Comment: You could have a page that calls the function, but there's no direct way to call PHP functions from JavaScript.